# Should I follow the prayer times of an app or from the local masjid?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

I am currently residing in Dublin, Ireland for work purpose.
I have downloaded Salatuk app from Android play store and follow that for Salat as we do not hear Azaan here and the place is new to me.

However isha is of 11:55 in the app and in masjid it happens around 11:15, which time should I follow?

Comment: You should follow the local timing you can also download a good calculation from moonsighting.com. Apps are only as useful as you know how to use them, many calculation methods only fit locally. The duplicate post explains it in details and generally.

Answer (score 1):

The Time for isha Prayer is after Twilight Disappears. But this will not happen during winter months for Cities near the poles, which is the case for Dublin now. 
Coming to How to pray in such situation, Authentic

his Hadith from IbnMajah where Prophet Mohammed (peace be upon him) said [link](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/36/150)

> .............. We said: 'O Messenger of Allah, how long will he stay
>   on earth?' He said: 'Forty days, one day like a year, one day like a
>   month, one day like a week, and the rest of his days like your days.'
>   We said: 'O Messenger of Allah, on that day which is like a year, will
>   the prayers of one day suffice us?' He said: **'Make an estimate of time
>   (and then observe prayer).**'............

This Hadith clearly says that five prayers every 24 Hrs even if sun doesn't set. When we have a direct reference from Prophet Mohammed (peace be upon him), then there is no wrong in estimating.

Based on the graph [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/ireland/dublin), both of the time seems to be an estimate (I am not an expert on this).

So in your case, You can follow any of these. But stick with one always. Aside from this, It is A Sunnah to pray in Congregation.

Answer (score 0):

sun reaches only -14 degrees 45 minutes below horizon at middle of night. so, normal night darkness does not reach. so, there is no isha, according to hadithes about times of 5 prayers every day. i think every person can try to choose best time for isha as he can, maybe even somebody can decide not to do/pray it. it can be made so that ends just before middle of night, maybe so that starts before middle of night and ends after it, maybe as starting after middle of night as qaza, maybe like in the app and in the masjid, long before middle of night, maybe at some point of time when sky becomes quickly darker, maybe when stars appear etc - different methods are possible. maybe we, who live in such place and time, should make it so that we have enough time to sleep and pray additional prayers and eat suhur. i also live in such place and i pray it currently/nowadays in magrib time and later than they pray it in local masjid.